# A positive constant bounding all $L^p$-norm of a function for $p>1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces

> Prove or disprove: If there exists a positive constant $M$ such that $||f||_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}<M$ for any $p > 1$, then $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

We have $$\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|^p\right)^{1/p} < M \implies \int_\mathbb{R}|f|^p < M^p.$$ Thus $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$. But since $1 < p$, wouldn't it automatically mean that $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Anyway, I'm thinking of using Holder's inequality to prove that the statement is true, since on the left side we will always have $||f||_1$. Let $1<p,p'<\infty$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1$, then we have $$||f||_1 \leq ||f||_p||f||_{p'}$$ and so $$\int _\mathbb{R}|f| \leq \left(\int_\mathbb{R}|f|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\left(\int_\mathbb{R}|f|^{p'}\right)^{\frac{1}{p'}}<M\cdot M = M^2.$$ Hence $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Did I miss out anything?

**EDIT.** I forgot that the left side should be a product of functions, let me rewrite it as: $$\int_\mathbb{R}f^2 < M^2$$ which doesn't seem helpful. Also, $\mathbb{R}$ has infinite measure. I'm starting to think that this statement is false.

Comment: In holder inequality the LHS should be the norm of a product of functions.

Comment: $L^p(\Omega) \subset L^q(\Omega)$ for $p > q$ is generally true when $\Omega$ is of finite measure. So applying Holder's should be more reasonable.

Comment: @Ilya that's true, so the left side should read $f^2$ instead, I tried breaking the right side to $f^{1/2}$ but I couldn't get suitable values of $p$ and $p'$. Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: The H\"older inequality gives $\|fg\|_1\le \|f\|_p\|g\|_{p'}.$ The inequality $\|f\|_1\le \|f\|_p\|f\|_{p'}$ is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of Fatou's Lemma. We have $\int |f|^{p} \leq M^{p}$. Letting $p \to 1$ ,say through the sequence $(1+\frac 1 n)$, we get $\int |f| \leq \lim \inf \int |f|^{p}\leq \lim \inf M^{p}=M$.

Comment: So we let our sequence of functions be $|f_n| = |f|^{1+\frac{1}{n}}$, converging to $|f|$ as $n$ tends to infinity. And by Fatou's lemma, $$\int |f| = \int \lim |f_n| = \int \lim \inf |f|^{1+\frac{1}{n}}  \leq \lim \inf \int |f|^{1+\frac{1}{n}} \leq \lim \inf M^{1+\frac{1}{n}} = M.$$ If I misunderstood please let me know.

Comment: @KelvinLian You have understood it correctly.